# save a date into phpmyadmin mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to insert date into database using php here is my php code and html input date tag

```
<form action="try.php" method="post">
<input type="date" name="date" id="date"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub"  />
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_Post['submit'])){
$see = $_POST['date'];
$insert_c = "insert into test(date) values ($see)";
$run = mysql_query($insert_c);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Go through and research for `php` again.

Comment: 1.stop using `mysql_*`,move towards `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statements`.2. check some latest tutorials and try to learn basics

Comment: Please don't use primitive data types like date, datetime, int, varchar as your column names.

Answer (score 0):

i have a suggestion for you. you can use mysqli_query insted of mysql_query. 
i think if you use mysql_query that is really nota good practice.

here the date will be in the format of mm/dd/yy so you need to give the same type in the database to i mean in phpmyadmin. or you can save the date in database by making the date field as varchar..

INSERT INTO `test`.`date` (`id`, `date`) VALUES ('1', '22/07/2017');

one more thing while you executing the query you have to pass the connection object too
example: mysql_query( $query, $conn );

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code

**NOTE**: Whenever your redirecting to the same page in the form action please use  the following code `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`  this specifies that you want to redirect to the same page. Instead of leaving the action blank or putting the same name as that of the current page.

One problem might be check your column data type it must of type **date**

For Eg the table must look something like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `created_date` date NOT NULL
)
```

And the following code does the job for inserting into that.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
   /* Her I am including my db_connect file which has db connection resource */
   include_once ('db_connect.php');
   /* User filter_input instead of $_POST */
   $createdDate = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'createdDate');
   /* Query to insert into test table */
   $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO test (created_date) VALUES ('".$createdDate."')");
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Insert Date</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <label>Created Date<label/>
    <input type="date" name="createdDate"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```